# Keep select select colour and add png as background

Tags: html, css, forms, select

I am trying to keep the colour of select input but also add the arrow png.
Can you pls help

```css
 select {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: url(../images/arrow_select.png) right 5px center no-repeat!important;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        padding: 15px;
        height: 47px;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<select id="dropdown">
        <option selected></option>
            <option>Mr</option>
            <option>Mrs</option>
            <option>Ms</option>
</select>
       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: JS fiddle or something which is executable?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(../images/arrow_select.png) right 5px center no-repeat!important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    padding: 15px;
    height: 47px;
```

```html
 <html>
 <body>
 <select id="dropdown">
        <option selected></option>
            <option>Mr</option>
            <option>Mrs</option>
            <option>Ms</option>
       </select>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify both the image and the color in a single CSS line to make it work.

```css
select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(https://via.placeholder.com/20x20/00ff00) right 5px center no-repeat, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 15px;
  height: 47px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work but thank you. What i've done is wrap it in a div and give that div the background colour.

Comment: @Alinacdn Funny, I can see it work here when running the snippet. Anyway, good luck with your project.